# Rotations around an axis

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I am given a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$

The transformation is linear and is defined by taking a vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and rotating it around the axis $L=span{(1,1,0)}$, which is a line in the $(x,y)$ plane, by $\frac{\pi}{4}$

My question: what is the difference between rotating a vector around the x or y or any axis in the $(x,y)$ plane, aren't we just changing the angle it makes with the rotation axis by $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Edit: To phrase better, what would be the result of a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$of the vector $(1,0,0)$ around the x axis, around the y axis and around the axis $L=span(1,1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating "about an axis" means rotating in the plane perpendicular to that axis; the angle of a point *with the axis* **does not change**.

For example, the rotation around the $x$-axis by $\pi/4$ is
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
0&1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2\\
0&1/\sqrt2& 1/\sqrt2
}
$$

Comment: If I were to rotate the vector $(0,0,1)$ around the $x$ axis using the 3x3 matrix you have given me, we would end up with the vector $(0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. How is it possible to rotate a vector perpendicular to the $x$ axis, I don't get it. Shouldn't the translation end up being the same vector since it turns around itself?

Comment: Your idea is backwards. The only vectors that don't get moved are those **on** the $x$-axis